# Declare char for comparison

Tags: string, rust, comparison, character, literals

As part of Advent of Code 2020 day 3, I'm trying to compare characters in a string to a specific character.

```rust
fn main(){
    let str_foo = 
"...##..#
##.#..#.";
    
    for char in str_foo.chars() {
        println!("{}", char == "#");
    }
    
}
```

The error I get is `expected char, found &str`.

I'm struggling to find a clean way to cast either the left or right side of the equality check so that they can be compared.

Comment: Double quotes are for strings, single quotes are for characters. So change `"#"` to `'#'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes for character literals. Fixed:

```rust
fn main() {
    let str_foo = 
"...##..#
##.#..#.";
    
    for char in str_foo.chars() {
        println!("{}", char == '#');
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1c7dd5bac7ca319486632e544a01ad18)